# Magnific-popup cancels all requests on open

Tags: magnific-popup

I have a lot of thumb images on one page, each of them triggers magnific popup on click. The problem is, that opening magnific popup before all images are loaded cancels all other requests and some images never load.

My question is how to prevent magnific popup from cancelling the requests.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set target:blank for the popup: like that, it will open the image in a new page and it won't stop the download of the current one...

Comment: Yes, this partly solves it. But i would prefer solution, where I can open images with magnific-popup even before all are loaded.

Comment: Have you tried it in different browsers? If it behaves in the same way than you will need to play with the 'defaults'...